# Creating a specific user interface design using JavaFX and scene builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm new to JavaFX and currently trying to create a rental system with UI using JavaFX with scene builder. I did some basic reading on both of them but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a specific design.

I thought about using either TableView or ListView but I don't think both of the layouts are suitable to create the design mentioned.

Thanks and hope someone can provide some idea or resources that I can study from.

The following image is the design that I mentioned above.[image: The design]

Comment: Hi, If you are new to JavaFx maybe it is a little bit hard to create a UI like this. To chose the most appropriate UI element is depending how you want to build your model. This view can be done with both the `TableView` and the `ListView`. As I can see it has many elements so, you have to build your model carefully then it will be easy to render it. At complex views I think the Scenebuilder is a disadvantage and it makes your work even harder rather than simplifying it.

Comment: In my opinion, `ListView` is the best choice for this. Each car rental option would be its own row in the `ListView`. If you want to use Scene Builder, what you should create is the row. Then you'd set the `cellFactory` of the `ListView` and use the row you created as the graphic of each cell. There are questions and tutorials about how to do such a thing that you can lookup for more information.

Comment: Due to the complexity of this, and the fact that it appears you have no need for the rows to be selectable, I would avoid using TableView and ListView.  Instead, I would create a [GridPane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) with three columns.  I agree with Sunflame; if you aren’t familiar with JavaFX, or at least familiar with UI frameworks in general, this is likely to be too difficult for a beginner.

Comment: Some idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401366/how-to-generate-buttonpicture-based-on-checkboxes-selection-in-javafx/53404336#53404336

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Actually what i only need is to be similar to the format. Example, the 1st column the picture of the vehicle, 2nd column is just 2 or 3 labels showing the vehicle name, availability and type. The last column is just a button.

Comment: @Slaw I was thinking about the concept you said but i'm not sure whether is is possible. I googled a bit apparently you can customise each row in the ListView using the setcellfactory method from the ListView class is that correct?

Comment: @VGR What if you have dozens or even hundreds of options? A `GridPane` would start to suffer performance-wise.

Comment: @CngY Yes, you customize the `ListCell`s of a `ListView` via `setCellFactory(Callback)`. And you can make the `ListCell` look any way you want by setting its `graphic` property.

Comment: @VGR I agree because i'm going use the design to display records from a database so i assumed ListView or TableView is going to be more ideal.

Comment: Just to note that you can customize a `TableView` in much the same way as a `ListView`, but you'd be customizing `TableCell`s via `TableColumn.setCellFactory(Callback)`.