# JavaFX ListView Cell multiple Graphics

Tags: listview, javafx

Is there anyway to add multiple grapgics to a JavaFX ListView cell?

```
lstTest.setCellFactory(param -> {
            ListCell<Test> cell = new ListCell<>();
            cell.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                handleCellDisplaying(cell);
            });
            cell.itemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> handleCellDisplaying(cell));
            return cell;
        });
```

and the handleCellDisplaying:

```
 private void handleCellDisplaying(ListCell<Test> cell) {
        FontIcon lockIcon = new FontIcon(FontAwesome.LOCK);
        cell.setGraphic(lockIcon);
        cell.setGraphic(bellIcon); //Multiple graphics here for the same cell
        cell.setGraphic(etc.etc.);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a single graphic. Put your icons into Pane component like HBox and set the HBox instance as graphic.

Comment: The `graphic` property can hold any arbitrary `Node`. Wrap the multiple graphics in an appropriate parent and then set the parent as the graphic.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401366/how-to-generate-buttonpicture-based-on-checkboxes-selection-in-javafx/53404336#53404336) helps. The images are not loaded lazily so performance is shady. Hopefully, this ideas can help you.